# Concatenate find command with other commans

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find, redirect

I am trying to index my file system. What I want to do, is: execute the command `find`, and for each entry save the last access time, last modified time, compute the hash and other operations. In order to do this I thought to do the following command:

```
find . -printf 'PATHNAME=%p -- NAME=%f -- SIZE=%s -- LAT=%a -- LCT=%c -- LMT=%t  \n' -exec file {} \; -exec md5sum {} \;
```

The output is something like:

```
PATHNAME=./script -- NAME=script -- SIZE=807 -- LAT=Fri Apr 15 16:39:52.0874615579 2016 -- LCT=Tue Apr 12 12:20:57.0767950320 2016 -- LMT=Tue Apr 12 12:20:57.0767950320 2016 <br>
./script: ASCII text <br>
cf1b934c226b194bee96106ea3f019a4  ./script
```

Now I would like to take all these parameters (for example parse them with `awk`) and put them somewhere (for example in a database). So, my question is: how can I redirect every time these 3 lines to a script for the parsing? Is there a better way to write the command?

Comment: So how exactly do you want the files to be parsed ?

Comment: From each file I want to get name, pathname, hash .. I saw that with -exec command I can execute additional operation on the files (In this case compute the hash and get the file type with "file" command).I would like to fill a sqlite table with different columns (name,pathname,last access time, hash, type,..). So I need to extract the informations from the previous command and put them in some variable before using them. For example I would like to create the variables name=exampleName, pathname=pathname, .. and use them as I prefer (in my case fill a table). I hope I was clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this (without the insert part in the database)

```
while read EMPTY_LINE; do
  read FILE_SIZE
  read FILE_AT
  read FILE_MT
  read FILE_CT
  read MIME_INFO
  read HASH FILE_PATH

  echo
  echo 'File path: '"$FILE_PATH"
  echo 'File size: '"$FILE_SIZE"
  echo 'File times (access - modified - changed): '"$FILE_AT - $FILE_MT - $FILE_CT"
  echo 'MIME stuff: '"$MIME_INFO"
  echo 'Hash: '"$HASH"
done < <(find . -type f -printf '\n' -exec stat --printf '%s\n%X\n%Y\n%Z\n' {} \; -exec file -b {} \; -exec md5sum {} \; )
```

Okay, so what exactly happens here, and why did I do it this way?

### Find command

First the command `find . -type f -printf '\n' -exec stat --printf '%s\n%X\n%Y\n%Z\n' {} \; -exec file -b {} \; -exec md5sum {} \;` is executed.

Let's break this down.

`find .` find stuff in `.` (which is the current directory)

`-type -f` find only files

`-printf '\n'` print an empty file for every file match

`-exec stat --printf '%s\n%X\n%Y\n%Z\n' {} \;` execute the stat command printing several file statistics which I specified myself - see `stat --help` for the statistics available

`-exec file -b {} \;` execute file command to determine MIME information. `-b` makes sure the filename is not printed along with it. We would ignore it anyway.

`-exec md5sum {} \;` execute md5sum command to calculate the md5 hash of the file contents.

So for so good. The `-exec` arguments are processed in the order specified.
This means per file match we'll get the following lines as

```
[FILE SIZE - from stat command]
[FILE LAST ACCESS TIME - from stat command]
[FILE LAST MODIFICATION TIME - from stat command]
[FILE LAST CHANGE TIME - from stat command]
[MIME INFO - from file command]
[HASH - from md5sum command] [FILE PATH - from md5sum command]
```

Let's try out the `find` command to see if it outputs everything as we'd expect.

```
[~/somedir]:$ find . -type f -printf '\n' -exec stat --printf '%s\n%X\n%Y\n%Z\n' {} \; -exec file -b {} \; -exec md5sum {} \;

1752
1441609114
1441609114
1441609114
ASCII text
4fb6f64ce9d07be553a81644b17fe69b  ./README.md

./tuptime-install.sh
1649
1441609114
1441609114
1441609114
Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
9ee7ad860bfa049d1d5f589fba218c6a  ./tuptime-install.sh
```

### Process the lines

There is a lot which can go wrong when parsing these things. What happens if there is a space in the filename? Or some other weird character? Or in the other parameters. To get rid of this problem and others I've used newlines explicitly. So we can read a full line and process it accordingly. No special parsing needed. (except for the hash part, but we'll get to that part in a bit)

The while loop will be fed the output of the `find` command. The while loop will run whilst there is a line left. We read the empty line every match starts with. The empty line is actually not really needed, but we'll use it to keep the ouput clean.

The script is pretty self explanatory. It reads the lines one by one into variables in the order we expect them to be present. After that we print them.

The way the `read` command works that if a single variable name is given, it will read the whole line into the given variable name. If multiple variables are given the line is split with the space character (by default) and put into the variables given. We only used it for the `md5sum` command as we couldn't specify an option that would get rid of the filename. We could have gotten the filename from `find`' or `stat`, but because md5sum doesn't have an option to omit it for efficiency reasons we'll be using that one.

I've also used the `unixtime` instead of the human readable format for timestamps. Having data in the most raw form if possible is in most cases preferred.

Only thing that would remain would be to put the data in the database.

### Example output of the script

```
File path: ./README.md
File size: 1752
File times (access - modified - changed): 1441609114 - 1441609114 - 1441609114
MIME stuff: ASCII text
Hash: 4fb6f64ce9d07be553a81644b17fe69b

File path: ./tuptime-install.sh
File size: 1649
File times (access - modified - changed): 1441609114 - 1441609114 - 1441609114
MIME stuff: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
Hash: 9ee7ad860bfa049d1d5f589fba218c6a
```